# How to fit Sencha GXT table in to the Div it contains

Tags: vaadin, gxt

Hi I am new to Sencha GXT. I would like to know, How can I style a GXT grid.
I want to know this because I am currently integrating the sencha GXT grid into a Vaadin widget. I have successfully done that but, the problem is with the styling. Is there any documentation we can prefer.
Major problem is the grid works perfectly when I manually give it a width and a height but, What want is  a to fit in to DIV it is in and re size the grid when the browser resizes.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/concepts/appearance/Appearance_3.html

Here's a link to the docs, basically it follow the GWT paradigm, if you've seen it before.

But since you want to integrate GXT Grid in a Vaadin widget I'd like to ask about your needings.
I know the standard Vaadin seems a little.."poor"..but I encourage you to check out the new Grid widget in Vaadin 7.4-beta (est release Feb.): it rocks!

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Main requirement is I need to handle Large number of data. Lets say 2 mil records with at least 20 columns in each record. BTW I tried the Grid, But it had some fall backs such as the method of multi selecting is not good. and it slows down with the requirements I mentioned.
Best thing with sencha is it Client side. so it is fast less load for the server, therefore it has more promise in handling large number of data with the liveGridView. But still the resizing problem is there, I will check the link you provided, And thanx for the help :)

Comment: 8Beta? did you mean 7.4 beta?

Comment: yeah 7.4 my bad, correcting right now :-)
Have you tried Grid widget from Sencha or from Vaadin? Because Vaadin's should manage to play with large numbers and also use hardware acceleration during rendering (following the patch notes)

Comment: Sorry again for the late reply...I used 7.4 beta grid with Vaadin. Well yeah it is better than Table regarding the speed but still not stable as the table( The records in the database are changing very fast so I need to update them per second. so Grid kind of cannot handle it. :) ), But it still is bit slow. and also It works fine with a large number of records but not with a Very large number of records I require.

Comment: I see, well it's a shame...hope they will improve it when they'll release it in february.

Comment: I am marking this as a correct answer this this leads to the correct direction :)